# Solr - Is there a way t find what attribute caused the retrival of the row in a query

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

When I query solr, I want act differently if the text appears in some columns than in others.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to distinguish or receive the column name that the result appeard in?
2. What if the text appears in two different columns - ColumnA and ColumnB. 
   it is more accurate (has higher score) in ColumnA. Can I receive that ColumnA has the highest score?
   Thanks.

Comment: About your second question: do you mean that you want to know which field was the "main" hit? If so, an example query (and pertinent configuration on your queryHandler from solrconfig.xml) might help in answering that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes there is, using Highlighting and the parameter [requireFieldMatch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.requireFieldMatch) in particular. Says on that page:

> If `true`, then a field will only be highlighted if the query matched in this particular field (normally, terms are highlighted in all requested fields regardless of which field matched the query).